# Creating a CSV string in Razor foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, foreach, httpcookie

I am trying to parse multiple page IDs into a cookie in Umbraco Razor.

I have this piece of code

```
@{ 
    var siteroot = Model.AncestorOrSelf(1);
    HttpCookie eventCookie = new HttpCookie("eventCookie");
}

@foreach (var child in siteroot.Descendants("Event").OrderBy("Date"))
{
    if (DateTime.Today <= child.Date)
    {
        @RenderPage("~/macroscripts/RenderEventBox.cshtml", child, false)
    }
}

@{
    Response.Cookies.Add(eventCookie);
}
```

What I want to do is to create  a CSV string in the foreach, with page IDs.

The page IDs should then be inserted in a cookie in which I can check for new IDs since the last time the user visited - for a "This is the new pages since your last visit" functionality.

But I am not sure how to do this.

The outcome that I want should look like

```
2525,4587,4789,4790,5858,5782,7899
```

which I then can put into a cookie.

Comment: Any reason you want to do this in razor, not at the controller action where you create model and pass it to the view?

Comment: The main reason being that I am not a backend-developer, so not to complicated programming :-)

I also might over complicate this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it solved quite simple with

```
@{
  var csv = "";
}

@foreach (var child in siteroot.Descendants("Event").OrderBy("Date"))
{
  csv += "," + @child.Id;
}
```